# How to Parse Custom (without Key) response in AMP-autosuggest (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amp-html, amp-list

Anyone tells me how can I parse my response in AMP-list. In AMP didn't find any solution how to parse own custom API response.

My Code.

```
<div
    class="autosuggest-container hidden"
    [class]="(showDropdown && query) ?
      'autosuggest-container' :
      'autosuggest-container hidden'"
  >
    <amp-list
      class="autosuggest-box"
      layout="fixed-height"
      height="120"
      src="http://lmyadpi.com/api.json?q=a"
      id="autosuggest-list"
    >

      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <amp-selector
          id="autosuggest-selector"
          keyboard-select-mode="focus"
          layout="container"
          on="
            select:
              AMP.setState({
                query: event.targetOption,
                showDropdown: false
              }),
              autosuggest-list.hide"
        >
          {{#results}}
            <div
              class="select-option no-outline"
              role="option"
              tabindex="0"
              on="tap:autosuggest-list.hide"
              option="{{.}}"
            >{{.}}</div>
          {{/results}}
          {{^results}}
            <div class="select-option {{#query}}empty{{/query}}">
              {{#query}}Sorry! We don't ship to your city {{/query}}
            </div>
          {{/results}}
        </amp-selector>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
  </div>
</div>

<amp-state
  id="allLocations"
  src="http://lmyadpi.com/api.json?q=a"
  "emptyAndInitialTemplateJson": [{
            "query": "",
            [[]]
        }]

  ></amp-state>
```

My API response :

```
[[
"1234",
"value2",
""
],
[
"6321123",
"value3",
""
],
[
"43934322",
"value4",
""
],
[
"43660213",
"value5",
""
],
[
"54373228",
"value6",
""
],
[
"410721327",
"value7",
""
]]
```

Comment: If the JSON file above is the `amp-list` JSON file specified by http://lmyadpi.com/api.json, then the structure is wrong. In `amp-mustache`, your asking for a parent key labeled `results`. where is that key in the JSON file? Also note the serving site must be HTTPS and CORS-enabled.

Comment: but my API use in multiple application and I am not able to change in this API.

Comment: am sorry for you but it `ain't gonna work` the only way it might work is if you specify `single-item` in `amp-list` and the use that item. You'll have to repeat for each `item` because i don't see a way you can iterate over the array.

Comment: this specific json formate by AMP is working but, in my condition, there are many other apps that using API formate as I mention on above so it really difficult

Comment: i'm not saying the JSON is wrong; it's just not in the form that can (easily) be processes by `amp-mustache`. The only other way you might do it is `amp-bind` but i don't think you can process an array using that method.

Comment: ya, I know but AMP community need to focus user can specify there customize json like Jquery